# UIDatePickerView as Timer with more values

Tags: iphone, ipad, timer, uipickerview, uidatepicker

The UIDatePicker with it's mode set on "Timer", only has values from 0 to 23 hours. I'd like to have more hours (like, up to 48 hours). It also shows a nice "floating" text next to the number on the selected row.

I can actually "imitate" the "floating" hours effect, by adding a label on top of the UIPickerView, but I'd lose the second column with the minutes interval, and I'd really like to have 30 minute interval on a pickerView. But I really need more values on the hours column. Any solutions?

Comment: Nobody is gonna leave your app running for 23 hours, much less 48 hours. For your kind of customization just use the UIPickerView instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Jason Coco said. Use a UIPickerView and set it up the way you need. Unless you are using the picker to send the timer length to a server and deliver a push notification, it seems like you may need to rethink your app. Unless a good multitasking solution is unveiled tomorrow at the iPhone OS 4 unveiling event.

Comment: Forget the question. I was having a hard time today, now I see how idiotic my question was :)