# Limiting the hour range for UIDatePicker in UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer mode?

Tags: iphone, ios5

I'd like to limit the range of the hours shown in the UIDatePicker in UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer mode from the current range of 0 - 23 to 0-6.

Is this feasible or do I have to roll out my own UIPicker control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [UIDatePicker's `countDownDuration`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDatePicker/countDownDuration) property.

I believe you can set the maximum value of the countdown there.  I'd recommend 6 * 60 * 60 (six hours * sixty minutes * sixty seconds).

Comment: Based on the documentation I initially thought that's the purpose of the property but what I actually see is that the picker's initial selected value is whatever countDownDuration is initialized to. I can still move the picker wheel and still select 23 hours with picker.countDownDuration=6*60*60.

Comment: Hmmm... sounds like the documentation should be clarified. How about [just using a regular UIPicker?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594432/uidatepickerview-as-timer-with-more-values)